# Phing and github

Tags: git, github, phing

I am trying to automate the deployment of code from a private github repo using phing but having trouble trying to find something that works like an SVN export.

I have read a few post on git archive and git checkout-index but have struggled to get these working with github. I get the impression that they are keen for us to use the zip download as they can cache this etc.

I wouldn't mind downloading the zip from github if there was a simple task in Phing to do this, a simple http task didn't work as it's over https and I guess some sort of authentication is needed first.

I managed to use gitclone task in Phing but the ".git" hidden folder is cloned too which is causing massive headaches...mainly because on subsequent builds I can't delete the build folder as it suggests certain git files, namely *.idx or *.pack are in use.

Has anyone had any luck with phing and a private github repo?

Thanks

Comment: is it a private repo? if not shouldn't the zip dl link be publicly available, thus no auth required?

Comment: Perhaps it might be easier if you setup a repo that is a clone from github and let phing clone (or git archive, git checkout-index) from that one locally?

Comment: It's a private repo, the download link returns a 404 when not logged in.

Comment: Then @magnus comment is the way to go

Comment: Magnus your approach definitely helped me rethink what I was trying to achieve and helped me get what I needed.

I ended up running this Phing task in the directory where I had my development code (same folder as ".git")

<exec command="git checkout-index --prefix ${build.dir} -a"></exec>

Comment: @Carlton - Why dont you post your answer and accept it for the sake of community ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@AYK My bad, have recently been exploring deployment options and think will roll with Capistrano...

Anyway this was my build script I ended up using temporarily with people's advice...

- Let's assume my app lives in "C:\app"
- Let's assume this build.xml file lives in "C:\app"
- Let's assume my app also contains a git repo "C:\app.git"
- Delete any build & deploy directories "C:\app\build" and "C:\app\deploy" that may exist from a previous build
- Make directories "C:\app\build" and "C:\app\deploy", will hold the git checkout and final code to deploy
- Excuting the git checkout as suggested checks out code from git and puts it into "C:\app\build"
- There are certain directories like docs I don't want to go out so I copy files I want to deploy to "C:\app\deploy"
- The problem I had with Phing is the scp part, needed ssh2 dll in PHP which I didn't have nor did I want to spend time trying to compile source for it.
- So all in all I achieved what I originally wanted with Phing but after spending an evening with Capistrano I'm converted

== build.xml ==

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project description="" name="MyProject" default="build" basedir=".">

    <property file="build.properties" />
    <tstamp>
    <format property="build.time" pattern="%Y%m%d_%H%I" />
    </tstamp>

    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <!-- Target: prepare                                 -->
    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <target name="prepare">
    <echo msg="Deleting old build and deploy dirs" />
    <delete dir="./build/" includeemptydirs="true" failonerror="true" />
    <delete dir="./deploy/" includeemptydirs="true" failonerror="true" />
    </target>

    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <!-- Target: create                                -->
    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <target name="create" depends="prepare">
    <echo msg="Creating fresh build and deploy directories" />
    <mkdir dir="./build/" />
    <mkdir dir="./deploy/" />
    </target>

    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <!-- Target: gitclone                              -->
    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <target name="gitcheckout" depends="create">
    <echo msg="Checking out latest code" />
    <exec command="git checkout-index --prefix ./build/ -a"></exec>
    </target>

    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <!-- Target: preparedeploy                         -->
    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <target name="preparedeploy" depends="gitcheckout">
    <echo msg="Preparing deploy" />
    <copy todir="./deploy/" >
        <fileset dir=".">
        <include name="cgi-bin/**" />
        <include name="htdocs/**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <mkdir dir="./deploy/logs" />
    </target>

    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <!-- Target: cleanup                                 -->
    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <target name="cleanup" depends="preparedeploy">
    <echo msg="Deleting build dir" />
    <delete dir="./build/" includeemptydirs="true" failonerror="true" />
    </target>

    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <!-- Target: build                                 -->
    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <target name="build" depends="cleanup, preparedeploy, gitcheckout, create, prepare">
    <echo msg="Starting build ${build.time}" />
    </target>

</project>
```